# MacPorts failed install port

Tags: macports

I have trouble installing PHP, MySQL and Apache2 using MacPorts. Currently my OS is Mavericks and i'm downloading the official binary package for mavericks (also tried compile from source and running selfupdate) but I got this error message:

```
--->  Building readline
Error: org.macports.build for port readline returned: command execution failed
Error: Failed to install readline
Please see the log file for port readline for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_readline/readline/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: apache2 apr-util mysql5 readline tcp_wrappers sqlite3 libedit pcre bzip2 autoconf213 gawk xz m4 gsed libtool libxml2 mhash pkgconfig
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port php5 failed
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the error message block within the log file:

```
/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_readline/readline/main.log
```

Also make sure xcode command line tools are installed.

FYI: I faced similar error in Mavericks. My case was:

- `opt` is a different partition which is mounted in `/Volumes/opt`
- `/opt` is a symbolic link to `/Volumes/opt`.

It has been solved after editing `/opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf` by replacing `/opt` with `/Volumes/opt`. Note sure this can help your case.